# What is the preferred way to develop a Python package without using setup.py?

Tags: pip, setuptools, setup.py, python-packaging, python-poetry

I am developing a Python package, and I don't want to have to keep running `pip install .` to reinstall my package every time I change something. Using the `-e` or `--editable` doesn't seem to work unless I have a `setup.py` file, nor does `--no-use-pep517`. I have a `pyproject.toml` instead, as is preferred nowadays if I am not mistaken. So, what is the preferred way to do this nowadays?

My package is just a CLI script, but it imports some functions from another file *in the same directory* called `utils.py`. When developing, I can't just run the script manually from the terminal, because then I get "*`name_of_package` is not a package*" from the line `from name_of_package.utils import function`. Whereas if I just have `from utils import function`, I can run the script from the terminal, but when I `pip install` it, it says "*there is no module named `utils`*".

I did install `poetry` and installed my dependencies, ran `poetry` shell and then tried to run my script with `poetry run /path/to/script.py`, but I kept getting an error that my package wasn't a package.

Comment: What is the issue with `setup.py`?

Comment: Also from, your description, there might be issues with your packaging in general and/or the way you start your CLI script. For example, make sure to use the `python -m package.cli` notation instead of `python package/cli.py`.

Comment: "My package is just a CLI script, but it imports [...] another file in the same directory" This seems broken at face value. Either your package should be *just* a CLI script, or a script and auxiliary library all in one package. Importing via *directories* usually is not a sound way to structure packages. Is your CLI script a standalone file that you run directly, or a proper [console script](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/entry_point.html#console-scripts) of your package?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi the script that I run is listed as a console script in my `setup.cfg`, and then there is as another script I import stuff from

Comment: @sinoroc I am not sure, I have just seen online that most people discourage using `setup.py`

Answer (score 16):

Nowadays, with [*setuptools*](https://pypi.org/project/setuptools/) as a [build back-end](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/glossary/#term-Build-Backend) you have the choice of using `setup.py`, [`setup.cfg`](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/declarative_config.html), [`pyproject.toml`](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/pyproject_config.html), or any combination of these three files to declare the project's metadata and configure the project's packaging. With `pyproject.toml` being the preferred one as it is standardized (see below). All these are compatible with editable installation (`python -m pip install --editable .`).

The *editable installation* mechanism has a standard specification (initiated by the [*PEP 660* document](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0660/)). And many build back-ends besides *setuptools* support it. These are the build back-ends I know of that support the standardized editable installation mechanism:

- [`enscons`](https://pypi.org/project/enscons/)
- `flit-core` (see [`flit`](https://pypi.org/project/flit/))
- `hatchling` (see [`hatch`](https://pypi.org/project/hatch/))
- [`maturin`](https://pypi.org/project/maturin/)
- [`meson-python`](https://pypi.org/project/meson-python/)
- `pdm-backend` (see [`pdm`](https://pypi.org/project/pdm/))
- `poetry-core` (see [`poetry`](https://pypi.org/project/poetry/))
- [`setuptools`](https://pypi.org/project/setuptools/)
- [`whey`](https://pypi.org/project/whey/)

All these build back-ends can have their configuration in [`pyproject.toml`](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/writing-pyproject-toml/) (including support for the standardized `[build-system]` section), and all but *Poetry* support the standardized `[project]` section. I have a [comparison table here](https://sinoroc.gitlab.io/kb/python/packaging_tools_comparisons.html#build-back-ends).

***References***:

- [Is `setup.py` deprecated?](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/discussions/setup-py-deprecated/)
- [How to modernize a `setup.py` based project?](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/modernize-setup-py-project/)
- [Writing your `pyproject.toml`](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/writing-pyproject-toml/)

Comment: Thanks, I will have a look into this